# What's the difference between lodash toNumber and parseInt?

Tags: javascript, lodash, parseint

I know Lodash often adds some extra checks or niceties to functions that already exist in JavaScript but it's not clear what `_.toNumber` specifically does that I wouldn't get with `parseInt`.

I'd prefer to use Lodash only when it provides benefits that aren't there with existing JavaScript functions but I can't see any in this case.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I think it is much better to simply look at the [_.toNumber source](https://github.com/lodash/lodash/blob/4.17.11/lodash.js#L12458) and that would practically answer your question:

```
function toNumber(value) {
  if (typeof value == 'number') {
    return value;
  }
  if (isSymbol(value)) {
    return NAN;
  }
  if (isObject(value)) {
    var other = typeof value.valueOf == 'function' ? value.valueOf() : value;
    value = isObject(other) ? (other + '') : other;
  }
  if (typeof value != 'string') {
    return value === 0 ? value : +value;
  }
  value = value.replace(reTrim, '');
  var isBinary = reIsBinary.test(value);
  return (isBinary || reIsOctal.test(value))
    ? freeParseInt(value.slice(2), isBinary ? 2 : 8)
    : (reIsBadHex.test(value) ? NAN : +value);
}
```

As you can see it does a bunch of other things in comparison to [parseInt](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt). To be more specific:

```js
console.log(_.toNumber(1),       parseInt(1))        // same 
console.log(_.toNumber('1'),     parseInt('1'))      // same  
console.log(_.toNumber('b'),     parseInt('b'))      // same  
console.log(_.toNumber({}),      parseInt({}))       // same 
console.log(_.toNumber(' 1 '),   parseInt(' 1 '))    // same
console.log(_.toNumber([1]),     parseInt([1]))      // same
console.log(_.toNumber(' 1a1 '), parseInt(' 1a1 '))  // NaN      1
console.log(_.toNumber([1,2]),   parseInt([1,2]))    // NaN      1
console.log(_.toNumber(false),   parseInt(false))    // 0        NaN
console.log(_.toNumber(!0),      parseInt(!0))       // 1        NaN
console.log(_.toNumber(!!0),     parseInt(!!0))      // 0        NaN
console.log(_.toNumber(5e-324),  parseInt(5e-324))   // 5e-324   5
console.log(_.toNumber(5.5),     parseInt(5.5))      // 5.5      5
console.log(_.toNumber(null),    parseInt(null))     // 0        NaN
console.log(_.toNumber(Infinity),parseInt(Infinity)) // Infinity NaN
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.11/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

So to summarize `_.isNumber` gives you more `expected / consistent` and I would argue `safer` results when it comes to parsing input with arrays, decimals, **falsy values** and strings. It would check the entire input vs `parseInt` which only cares about the first valid value as you can see from the examples above. It also handles better the negate operator (`!`) etc.

So overall it does have its uses vs `parseInt`

**Note**: What is a gotcha here is that both `_.toNumber` and `parseInt` return `NaN` for `undefined` which considering how `_.toNumber` deals with the rest of the falsy values one would expect to return `0` vs `NaN`:

```
console.log(_.toNumber(undefined), parseInt(undefined))  // NaN NaN
```

Comment: Good point, I should have just checked the source to begin with. I'll do this for future lodash questions like this because I always think this way.

Comment: I would like to suggest correction to the above answer. I think it might be misleading by saying that lodash toNumber gives more expected results.

Please extend your examples with following values:
10%
100$
$100

or any other currency character. Both parseInt and parseFloat handles them as one would expect, where toNumber returns NaN.

Answer (score 3):

`_.toNumber` converts a given input to a number if such a conversion is possible, otherwise returns `NaN`. The `parseInt` and `parseFloat` methods also work in same manner (the former will only return integers though), however, they are much more lax in their parsing rules. _.toNumber is significantly more restrictive.

For eg, with same input `'5.2a'`, `parseInt` would return `5`, `parseFloat` would return `5.2`, and `_.toNumber` would return `NaN`. The former two ignore everything after the first unrecognised character and return the number formed by all parsed characters till that point. The last one however returns NaN if an unrecognised character is encountered.

`_.toNumber` is comparable and functionally same to `Number` function.